# Data masking in Azure Datalake Store Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

We've multiple pipelines which ingest data from various data sources into Azure Datalake Store-Gen2. Since, we have couple of trusted datasets which needs Data masking in addition to ACL and RBAC implementation.

Is there any way that we can mask the data in Azure Datalake Store-Gen1/Gen2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data) article this is not yet possible.

You can only use RBAC and ACL.